# collapse of the soviet union - connotation?

Tags: connotation

does "the COLLAPSE of the soviet union" have a negative or postive connotation? I am looking for a neutral expresion.

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: It depends on your perspective whether this was good or bad.

Comment: Did you look for alternatives in a thesaurus?

Comment: "Collapse" generally implies "failure".

Comment: Well, that's impossible. If you have a  political entity, a complete whole, and it comes to an end, I cannot think of a neutral expression to refer to that. It breaks up, it comes apart, it separates into constituent parts, it divides up into parts, and so on. Isn't

Comment: @Lambie - "Dissolve" would be about the least pejorative term for the breakup of a government.

Comment: See [Notes to Reviewers](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7913/142322).

Answer (score 1):

Formally, there's the **dissolution**, but that happened as a result of the collapse, yes?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissolution_of_the_Soviet_Union

Answer (score 0):

The term *collapse* can be used in a neutral or positive way

> The *collapse* of the building being demolished went exactly as planned.

However, when describing an institution (or a person), the term does seem to have a negative connotation.

> (Of an institution or undertaking) fail suddenly and completely:
>   *in the face of such resolve his opposition finally collapsed*

*[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/collapse)*

*Failure* tends to be negative.

Perhaps the term *[devolution](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/devolution)* may suit

> The transfer or delegation of power to a lower level, especially by central government to local or regional administration.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score -2):

To me "collapse" is similar in meaning to "failure" in this context, and therefore is negative.  For a neutral expression i'd suggest "**breakup**" (as a noun, use "break up" for the verb).

Technically, also, i don't think that the Soviet Union itself collapsed.  You could say that **communism** collapsed I think, as this is the social institution, whereas the Soviet Union was more of a geographical institution.  I'm not sure about this though.